# writing data from forms to a SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm new to flask and making a microblogging application to get to know it.
I'm having a problem , The registration details of a new user are not being written to the database.
can someone help me?

Hers's my views function:

```
from app import app,db
from .forms import LoginForm,Register
from flask import render_template,session,redirect,url_for
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, 
login_required
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form=LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html',
                            title='Sign In',
                            form=form)
@app.route('/user',methods=['GET','POST'])
def user():
    return render_template('user.html')


@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def registration():
    reg=Register()
    if reg.validate_on_submit():
        u=User()
        u.username=register.username.data
        u.First_name=register.First_name.data
        u.Last_name=register.Last_name.data
        u.password=register.password.data
        u.email=register.email.data
        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('register.html',
                            title='New Registration',
                            register=reg)
```

Here's my model:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(32),index=True,unique=True)
    First_name=db.Column(db.String(32))
    Last_name=db.Column(db.String(32))
    password=db.Column(db.String(32))
    email=db.Column(db.String(20))
    posts=db.relationship('Post',backref='author',lazy='dynamic')

    def get_id(self):
        try:
            return unicode(self.id)  # python 2
        except NameError:
            return str(self.id)      #python 3

class Post(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    body=db.Column(db.String(300))
    timestamp=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey(User.id))
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField,BooleanField,PasswordField,validators


class LoginForm(Form):
    username=StringField('username',[validators.DataRequired()])
    password=PasswordField('password',[validators.DataRequired()])
    remember_me=BooleanField('remember me',default=False)

class Register(Form):
    first_name=StringField('f_name',[validators.DataRequired(message=None)])
    last_name=StringField('l_name',[validators.DataRequired(message=None)])
    email=StringField('email',[validators.Email(message='Enter a valid Email ID')])
    password=PasswordField('reg_password',[validators.Length(min=8,max=20)])
    username=StringField('u_name',[validators.DataRequired(message=None)])
    confirm_password=PasswordField('c_password',[validators.DataRequired(),validators.EqualTo('password',message='passwords should match')])
```

here's the template for the registration page:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="Login">
{{ register.hidden_tag() }}
<h1>New Registration</h1>
<p>First Name: {{ register.first_name }}</p>
<p>Last Name: {{ register.last_name}}</p>
<p>email:{{ register.email }}</p>
<p>username: {{register.username}}</p>
<p>Password:{{register.password}}</p>
<p>Password:{{register.confirm_password}}</p>
<p type="submit"><a href='/user' value="Register">Register</a></p>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: the form data is not being written to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment but is it possible you made a lot of changes in the code? I believe a review is necessary. For example the mapping between the elements in the form 'register' and the view don't seem to add up:

```
u.First_name=register.First_name.data
...
first_name=StringField('f_name',[validators.DataRequired(message=None)])
```

but also the references in the view seem to point to 'register' instead of reg:

```
reg=Register()
if reg.validate_on_submit():
    u=User()
    u.username=register.username.data
```

Also when going through your code I also made changes to the button in your template, as a quick change I changed the code for the button in:

```
<button type="submit">register</button>
```

It was for me unclear why you placed a link to the user page there (while using a redirect in your view):

```
<p type="submit"><a href='/user' value="Register">Register</a></p>
```

Comment: thanks dude. The link to the user page in the HTML was the main culprit.
 I'm relatively new to programming,so I tend to make these type of mistakes.
You were a big help.